# Resistor value selection for PWM dimming of Meanwell LED driver

Tags: arduino, led, resistors, pwm, dimming

I'm controlling a Meanwell LED driver's dimming function using 0-5V PWM from an Arduino, stepped up to the 0-10V PWM the driver expects.

- [Here is the circuit.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EO1U.png)

[image: 5V to 10V PWM Converter Circuit]

- '0-5v' is the 5V PWM from the Arduino
- 'VCC' is the **10V 500uA** wire from the driver's DIM+
- '0-10v' is the 10V PWM output back to the driver's DIM-
- 'Q1 NPN' is a 2N2222 transistor

I could use some guidance on selecting proper resistor values for R1 and R2, given the function of the circuit and VCC at 10V/500uA.  I've been advised that the given values may be inappropriate for such a low-current VCC.

(I recognize that this circuit inverts the PWM signal and have accounted for this software-side.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please, post the picture here. Your score should be enough now

Comment: A link to the LED driver is important.

Comment: I don't have the reputation to include a second link; I'll drop it here: http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/260/HLG-185H-C-SPEC-806161.pdf

Comment: I don't think that works the way you think it does.  The DIM- is the low side of the input, and DIM+ is the high side.  You won't get very far pulling the low side up.  I would connect DIM-to the ground on the Arduino.  The transistor then pulls DIM+ down to generate the PWM.  Alternatively, use an optocoupler.  The documentation isn't very clear, though, and you may actually need a 10V supply to drive the DIM+ rather than just shorting it to ground.

Comment: Don't miss this:  DO NOT connect "DIM- to -V"

Comment: @JRE I don't see how that could work with four of these dimming circuits per Arduino.  I also don't understand why simulating 10V PWM by switching the driver's 10V DIM+ signal on and off with a 5V PWM signal won't be effective?  That's specifically what this circuit was created for by the original light fixture designer.

Comment: @Misunderstood Yep.

Comment: Your circuit isn't switching DIM+ on and off.  You have DIM+ and DIM- connected through R2, and Q1 connects DIM- to the ground of the Arduino on every PWM pulse.  Since the Arduino ground isn't connected to the LED driver at all, not much will happen when Q1 is triggered.

Comment: I don't have an answer yet, but I know several circuits that don't work... The MeanWell outputs 10-12V at <100uA on DIM+ with respect to DIM-. I tried PWM using an MCT62 opto-darlington and other opto-couplers to short DIM+ to DIM-, but the capacitance is too high, so rise time suffers badly. I tried direct coupling with just a transistor (similar to above schematic) and it "works", except that after shorting DIM+ to DIM- (light off) for several hours the MW stops outputting 10V so no way to turn lights on again (I have MW XLG-150). Now trying PWM via opto using 5V to 9V DC-DC converter...